# Example of nice isomorphism between Cl$_{p,q}(\mathbb R)$ and matrix algebras over $\mathbb R,\mathbb C,\mathbb H,\mathbb R^2,\mathbb C^2,\mathbb H^2$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, clifford-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cl{Cl}$It is known that every Clifford Algebra $\Cl(Q)$ over the real numbers where $Q: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a non-degenerate quadratic form is isomorphic to a matrix algebra over $\{\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H, \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R, \mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C, \mathbb H \oplus \mathbb H\}$. *What I'm wondering is whether, for any such $Q$, there is an isomorphism so that the generators of the Clifford algebra are represented as normal matrices*. In order to define a *normal* matrix, we need to define an involution for the above six algebras: For $\mathbb R$, we define $z^* = z$; for $\mathbb C$, we define $(a + bi)^* = a - bi$; for $\mathbb H$, we define $(a + bi + cj + dk)^* = a - bi - cj - dk$; for $R \oplus R$ for any $*$-ring $R$, we define $(w,z)^* = (w^*,z^*)$.

I know that the so-called Dirac representation for $\Cl_{n,n}(\mathbb R)$ satisfies my criteria. But I would like a reference for a "normal representation" for $\Cl_{p,q}(\mathbb R)$ for any $p$ and $q$. I can work this out myself, but it's tedious, and I'd like to see if there's a reference.

---

### Alternative phrasing

An alternative way of phrasing the question is that we want to strengthen the ring isomorphisms in the classification theorem for Clifford algebras into $*$-ring isomorphisms. Details:

[Here is the Wikipedia article on $*$-rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra).

$\Cl_{p,q}(\mathbb R)$ can be made into a $*$-ring by defining $e^* = \begin{cases} -e, &\text{if } e^2 = -1 \\ e, &\text{if } e^2 = 1\end{cases}$ for any generator $e$, and extending to $\Cl_{p,q}(\mathbb R)$ by linearity.

Likewise, $A \in M_n(R)$ (where $R$ is some $*$-ring) can have $A^*$ defined as $(A^*)_{ij} = A_{ji}^*$.

This then turns $M_n(R)$ into a $*$-ring where $R$ is any of $\{\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H, \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R, \mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C, \mathbb H \oplus \mathbb H\}$.

The question is, does there exist a $*$-ring isomorphism between $\Cl_{p,q}(\mathbb R)$ and some $M_n(R)$, as opposed to merely a ring isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

The required isomorphism between $*$-rings, with a direct and constructive proof, is given here [[1]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959090282H). The required theorem is given as Theorem 2. The proof is all of section 3.

[1] - "Matrix representations of Clifford algebras". Linear Algebra and its Applications. 1990.